# Does it matter that my parents' last name is different to mine in my passport, for a visitor visa for my parents where my husband is the sponsor?

Tags: visas

My husband is planning to apply for a visitor visa to the US for my parents. My last name and my parents' last name is different. Even in my birth certificate and marriage certificate it was different.
Is this an issue for getting a US visitor visa?

I heard from some people that since my husband is sponsoring there will be no issue, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Which country do your parents want to travel to?

Comment: They want to travel to USA

Comment: Is this difference in last names a normal thing in your culture?